# how to setup phpmyadmin on nginx with laraval?

Tags: mysql, laravel, nginx, phpmyadmin

does anybody know how to setup `phpmyadmin` on `nginx` server (ubuntu) with `laravel`?..

my site is built with laravel and hosted on `/var/www/mysite/`
the default nginx-config is disabled...site is not hosted under the default `html` directory, but on the `/var/www/mysite` directory...(*because i plan to host one more site on the same server in future*)

`Laraval` installation works, but i am unable to access phpmyadmin..
i have already tried the `ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/mysite/` approach but laravel gives a 404 error

the guides found on the internet do not specify how to install `phpmyadmin` onto a `nginx-laravel` combo.. the settings are different than a normal `nginx` only installation..

does anybody know the correct steps to make it working?

Comment: phomyadmin is agui for mysql written in php and the website describes very good , how to copy the files and setup it must be copied of course also in the www folder or subfolders(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not about use specifically phpmyadmin, but how to use more than one site under the same host with nginx, it doesn't matter if it is phpmyadmin. If you already have your website at /var/www/mysite you cannot map the phpmyadmin to the same path (symlink), you have to map it to another folder, like this:

```
ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/phpmyadmin/
```

Make sure that your .conf files at nginx are right, post them here.

Remember to reload the server and it could be the case to map the public phpmyadmin folder (that contains index file) if it exists.

Check it out: https://fedingo.com/how-to-host-multiple-domains-on-one-server-in-nginx/

English isn't my first language, ask me again if you didn't understand something.

Comment: hi @Geovanni Cassemiro Rocha, thanks very much for your help.....i have a doubt... in the link you gave, there are two servers configured with two different domain-names... but my laraval and phpmyadmin are using same domain-names.... so how do i solve that?

Comment: To that you can use "location" at your config file, and you can access this way: "website.com/phpmyadmin" and "website.com". But this "route" will not be configured inside laravel, it will be only at nginx. Depending on how you run phpmyadmin and your website, you could need to set different ports to each location to use, but it depends, it's not mandatory. Take a look at this link to know more about location in nginx: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/web-server/

Comment: ok thanks very much @geovanni Cassemiro Rocha